# Android bitmap compress method is returning same size image even on different quality value

Tags: android, android-bitmap, android-image, image-compression

I am trying to scale and then compress an image file as PNG, the camera image format is in JPG and it is being scaled successfully and but it is still not being converted to PNG.
Secondly I think `compress` method returns different sized `byteArray` for different quality but I am getting same sizes even on changing the quality parameter value.

Here is the method I have written:

```
   fun compressImage(file: File): File {
        val outputBounds = 600
        val scaleOptions = BitmapFactory.Options()
        scaleOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.path, scaleOptions)

        val scaleFactor =   if(scaleOptions.outHeight > outputBounds || scaleOptions.outWidth > outputBounds)
                                        kotlin.math.max(scaleOptions.outWidth/outputBounds, scaleOptions.outHeight/outputBounds)
                                    else 1

        val outOptions = BitmapFactory.Options()
        outOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor.roundToInt()
        outOptions.inPreferredConfig = Config.RGB_565;
        outOptions.inDither = true;
        val decodedBMP = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.path, outOptions)

        var byteOutStream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        val newFile = File(file.path)
        val fileOutputStream = FileOutputStream(newFile, false)
        var quality = 60
        decodedBMP.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, quality, byteOutStream)

        fileOutputStream.write(byteOutStream.toByteArray())
        fileOutputStream.flush()

        fileOutputStream.close()
        return newFile
    }
```

I passed a file as parameter here and I am overwriting the file with the compressed image.

**Update**

I tried using `Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG` as bitmap compression config and that is compressing the image size but with apparently losing quality (I mean picture looks like pixelated), I read `Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG` gives you lossless compression but it is not working.

Comment: Have you checked the size of your file parameter? Cause if height or width of file parameter isn't greater than the outPutBounds it will always be a scaled factor of 1.@suvodipMondal

Comment: Yes in that case picture won't be resized but will remain the same but compression is not working

Comment: Try changing Config.RGB_565 to ARGB_8888 @suvodipMondal

Comment: @i_o No that is not working too, I updated some more information about the problem, I cannot understand why the file is not being converted to png

Answer (score 1):

In the Android Developer reference docs it says:

JPEG
Added in API level 1 
public static final Bitmap.CompressFormat JPEG
Compress to the JPEG format. ***quality of 0 means compress for the smallest size***. ***100 means compress for max visual quality***.

PNG
Added in API level 1 
public static final Bitmap.CompressFormat PNG
***Compress to the PNG format. PNG is lossless, so quality is ignored.***

Here is the answer. Since quality is ignored Compress to format.PNG is lossless, which means it will not compress.

Comment: Ok I changed that scale factor but still my image is not being compressed, it is being resized only

Comment: switch the order of the lines: fileOutputStream.write and fileOutputStream.flush()  I think It has something to do with it. I remember having a problem like this before @suvodipMondal

Comment: Actually I have updated some information, can you help me about this?

Comment: Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG is compressing the file but the file Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG is not converting my file PNG